# Need to add depth class according to parent id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add depth class according to parent_id.

**Json Data :**

```
[
{"id":1,"name":"one","parent_id":0},
{"id":2,"name":"two","parent_id":0},
{"id":3,"name":"three","parent_id":0},
{"id":4,"name":"four","parent_id":0},
{"id":5,"name":"five","parent_id":0},
{"id":6,"name":"one","parent_id":2},
{"id":7,"name":"two","parent_id":6},
{"id":8,"name":"three","parent_id":6},
{"id":9,"name":"four","parent_id":8},
{"id":10,"name":"five","parent_id":8},
]
```

**Result Should be :**

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="depth-0 menu-item-1"><li>
    <li class="depth-0 menu-item-2"><li>
    <li class="depth-1 menu-item-6"><li>
    <li class="depth-2 menu-item-8"><li>
    <li class="depth-3 menu-item-9"><li>
    <li class="depth-3 menu-item-10"><li>
    <li class="depth-2 menu-item-7"><li>
    <li class="depth-0 menu-item-3"><li>
    <li class="depth-0 menu-item-4"><li>
    <li class="depth-0 menu-item-5"><li>
</ul>
```

i have tried

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    if(item.parent_id > 0){
        $(this).addClass('depth-1');
    }
});
```

if item `parent_id` is `0` then class should be `depth-0` if item has `parent_id` `(child item)` then class should be `depth-1` and if has `(sub child item)` `depth-2`. any one can guide me how can do this ?

Comment: This would probably be easier to do if you refactored the JSON data; is that a possibility?

Comment: @Explosion Pills NO! i have already did a lot work using this structure.

Comment: @Explosion Pills this is same as WordPress did with his menu items.

Comment: I have not totally understood how you want your classes to be set. If `parent_id == 0` => `depth-0`, `parent_id > 0` => `depth-1` and when do you have to set `depth-2`?

Comment: @LightStyle actually i am unable to make correct logic.

Comment: What do you mean with "sub child item"? How can I understand if it is it?

Comment: @LightStyle look at json data item `6` is child of `2` and `7,8` child of `6` and `9,10` child of `8`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

```
var depths = [];

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    depths[item.id] = (depths[item.parent_id] || 0) + 1;
});
```

This would give you an array with depths (starting from 1)

So for the data

```
var data = [
{"id":1,"name":"one","parent_id":0},
{"id":2,"name":"two","parent_id":0},
{"id":3,"name":"three","parent_id":0},
{"id":4,"name":"four","parent_id":0},
{"id":5,"name":"five","parent_id":0},
{"id":6,"name":"one","parent_id":2},
{"id":7,"name":"two","parent_id":6},
{"id":8,"name":"three","parent_id":6},
{"id":9,"name":"four","parent_id":8},
{"id":10,"name":"five","parent_id":8},
];
```

So depths array would be:

```
[undefined, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4]
```

ie menu item 1 has depth of 1, menu item 6 has depth of 2... similar to your example.

Now iterate over the depths array & generate the menu items...

Comment: result should be `[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]`

Comment: Kept the example simple for you to understand. The depths simply start from 1 instead of 0... Please do the necessary modifications (like subtracting 1) to suit your needs.

Comment: `depths[item.ID] = (depths[item.menu_item_parent] || 0) + 1;
depths[item.ID]-1`

This code solved my problem.
Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1):

Implementing loxxi's answer you can do it this way:

```
$.each(data, function(i, item) {
    depthsTemp[item.id] = (depthsTemp[item.parent_id] || 0) + 1;
});
depths = $.map(depthsTemp, function(item) {
    return --item;
}).splice(1);
function buildList(depthList) {
    var html = '<ul class="menu">\n';
    for (var i = 0; i < depthList.length; i++) {
        html += '<li class="depth-' + depthList[i] + ' menu-item-' + (i + 1) + '"></li>\n';
    }
    html += '</ul>';
    return html;
}
```

See the [working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k6Kay/) of this